# App crashing when App is setting delegate of FirebaseMessaging

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app try to use `Firebase` remote notification, I followed the Firebase guide. Now my app crashes in `AppDelegate` where I am trying to set the delegate of `Firebase` messaging.

Here is the code

```
[FIRApp configure];
[FIRMessaging messaging].delegate = self;
```

In the second line it crashes with crash message as given below:

> +[FIRInstanceIDCheckinPreferences preferencesFromKeychainContents:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10ef2a538
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '+[FIRInstanceIDCheckinPreferences preferencesFromKeychainContents:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10ef2a538'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001116671e6 **exceptionPreprocess + 294  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x0000000110cfc031 objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00000001116e86c4 +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] +
>   132   3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001115e9898
>   ___forwarding_** + 1432   4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001115e9278 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120  5   MobilePro Dev
>   0x000000010ed09af3 -[FIRInstanceIDCheckinStore
>   cachedCheckinPreferences] + 407   6   MobilePro Dev
>   0x000000010ed0d73a -[FIRInstanceIDStore resetCredentialsIfNeeded] +
>   145   7   MobilePro Dev                       0x000000010ed0d230
>   -[FIRInstanceIDStore initWithCheckinStore:tokenStore:delegate:] + 174     8   MobilePro Dev                       0x000000010ed0d154
>   -[FIRInstanceIDStore initWithDelegate:] + 142     9   MobilePro Dev                       0x000000010ed10acc -[FIRInstanceIDTokenManager init] + 105  10 
>   MobilePro Dev                       0x000000010ed022ae -[FIRInstanceID
>   setupTokenManager] + 50   11  MobilePro Dev
>   0x000000010ed0225c -[FIRInstanceID start] + 90    12  libdispatch.dylib 
>   0x0000000114c4f7ec _dispatch_client_callout + 8   13  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x0000000114c50d64 dispatch_once_f + 285  14  MobilePro Dev
>   0x000000010ecfefac +[FIRInstanceID instanceID] + 45   15  MobilePro Dev
>   0x000000010ed26a6a -[FIRMessaging initPrivately] + 38     16  MobilePro
>   Dev                       0x000000010ed26939 **25+[FIRMessaging
>   messaging]_block_invoke + 41  17  libdispatch.dylib
>
>   0x0000000114c4f7ec _dispatch_client_callout + 8   18  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x0000000114c50d64 dispatch_once_f + 285  19  MobilePro Dev
>
>   0x000000010ed2690d +[FIRMessaging messaging] + 45     20  MobilePro Dev
>
>   0x000000010eaa9ac3 -[AppDelegate
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 323     21  UIKit
>
>   0x00000001128d96fb -[UIApplication
>   _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 278  22  UIKit                               0x00000001128db172
>   -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4123   23  UIKit                               0x00000001128e05cb
>   -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1677   24  UIKit                               0x0000000112ca2f7e
>   __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke
>   + 866     25  UIKit                               0x0000000113075a39 +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 153    26  UIKit                               0x0000000112ca2bba
>   -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 236     27  UIKit                               0x0000000112ca33db
>   -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 675  28  UIKit
>
>   0x0000000113614614 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas
>   _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke
>   + 299     29  UIKit                               0x00000001136144ae -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 433     30  UIKit                               0x00000001132f875d
>   __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke
>   + 221     31  UIKit                               0x00000001134f34b7 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 100   32  UIKit                               0x00000001132f8627 -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction
>   performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]
>   + 223     33  UIKit                               0x00000001130750e0 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 392     34  UIKit                               0x00000001128deeac
>   -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 515     35 
>   UIKit                               0x0000000112eb1bcb
>   -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 361   36 
>   FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001176452f3 -[FBSSceneImpl
>   _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 331    37  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011764dcfa
>   __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 225     38 
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114c4f7ec
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 8  39  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114c54db8 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 592  40 
>   FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000117679470
>   __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 24     41  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011767912e
>   -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 439  42  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011767968e -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] +
>   45    43  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111609bb1
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   44  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001115ee4af
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 271   45  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001115eda6f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263    46  CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001115ed30b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635     47  GraphicsServices
>   0x000000011779ca73 GSEventRunModal + 62   48  UIKit
>   0x00000001128e2057 UIApplicationMain + 159    49  MobilePro Dev
>   0x000000010eac56cf main + 111     50  libdyld.dylib
>   0x0000000114ccc955 start + 1  51  ???
>   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Has anyone found any solution for this ?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't use pods, you must to add the objC linker flag for your target.

From the documentation:

"Integrate without CocoaPods
If you don't want to use Cocoapods, you can still take advantage of the Firebase SDKs by importing the frameworks directly.

Download the framework SDK zip. This is a ~1GB file and might take some time to download.

Unzip the file, then review the README for the Frameworks that you want to include in your app.

**Add the ObjC linker flag in your Other Linker Settings in your target's build settings.**"

Link:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1490/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

When you call a delegate, you must ensure that all the required methods of that delegate are written.

Check the following method is called in your Appdelegate.

```
-(void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveRegistrationToken:(NSString *)fcmToken 
{
}
```

Or ensure that **FIRMessagingDelegate** is written in your Appdelegate

```
@interface AppDelegate ()<FIRMessagingDelegate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the Firebase configure method.

Call it as,

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 42.0), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [FIRApp configure];
 });
```

It will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
import FirebaseMessaging
FirebaseApp.configure()
Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
```

> //MARK:- Messaging Delegate Method ..............................

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
            let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
            print("FCM token: \(token ?? "")")
}
```